# VUE рендер шаблона при динамическом props

Tags: vue.js, компоненты, render

На странице нужно отобразить select, данные приходят с запроса т.е. на сервер организована функция для всех запросов, соответственно когда данные приходят то компонент уже отрендерен, есть ли способ отрендерить компонент с пришедшими данными. Вообще идея такая с сервера приходит ответ, "заполняется" select, потом то что выбрано в селекте используется как фильтр.
Сейчас организовано так:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    strict: true,
    state:{
        user:{
            name:'Name',
            id:0,
            password:'password',
            history:[],
        },
        nomenclature:'none',
        page:'',
        pangination:{
            length:0
        },
    },
    mutations: {
        nomenclature(state,resp){
            var nomenclature={};
            nomenclature.manufacture=resp.manufacture;
            nomenclature.group=resp.group;
            nomenclature.model=resp.model;
            state.nomenclature=nomenclature;
        }
    },
    getters:{
        arrModel:state=>{
            var list=[];
            var history=state.user.history;
            for (var i = 0; i < history.length; i++) {
                if (list.indexOf(history[i].modelID)===-1) list.push(history[i].modelID);
            };
            return list;
        }
    }
});


var select={
    template:'<select>'+
            '<option>Все</option>'+
            '<option v-for="item in arrModel">item</option>'+
        '</select>',
    computed:{
        arrModel(){return this.$store.getters.arrModel;}
    }
}


var tableUserHistory = {
    props:['view'],
    template:'<div>'+
    '<table class="highlight">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<th class="center">№</th>'+
            '<th class="center"> Модель'+
        '</th>'+
            '<th class="center">'+
                'Статус'+
            '</th>'+
            '<th class="center">'+
                '№ Изделия'+
            '</th>'+
            '<th class="center">'+
                'Дата'+
            '</th>'+
            '<th class="center">Комментарий</th>'+
        '</tr>'+

        '<tr>'+
            '<th class="center"></th>'+
            '<th class="center"> '+ 
                '<div>{{test}}</div>'+
                '<my-select></my-select>'+
            '</th>'+ .....''
        components:{
            'my-select':select,
        }
var userHistory = {
    data:function(){
        return {
            view:{
                tableRows:8,
                currentPage:0
            }
        }
    },
    template:'<div>'+
                '<find></find>'+
                '<table-user-history v-bind:view="view"></table-user-history>'+
                '<pagination v-bind:view="view" v-on:currentPageChange="currentPageChange"></pagination>'+
            '</div>',
    methods:{
        currentPageChange:function(page){this.view.currentPage=page}
    },
    computed:{
        userHistory() {return this.$store.state.user.history},
    },
    components:{
        'table-user-history':tableUserHistory,
        'pagination':pagination
    }   
};


var main = new Vue({
    el:'.vMain',
    data:{
        user:{id:0, name:'Name', password:'password'},
        page:'user-history', //start page
    },
    store,
    methods:{
        setPage:function(page){
            this.page=page;

            console.log(page)
        },
        outUser:function(){$storage.writeToken('out')}, //clear token, href reload page
    },
    components:{
        'user-history':userHistory,
        'admin-page':adminPage,
    }
});
```

Вот в этом случае в консоле все данные отображаются все как бы все хорошо, но вот селект не изменяется, до этого был опыт работы с AngularJS. Вот в ангуляре есть функция компиляции шаблона, я так думаю что и в Vue должно быть что то подобное. Ну или какой-то другой подход нужен, пробывал через render? результат тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, у вас запрос на сервер происходит в теле `computed` свойства `arrModel`

Это в корне не верно, `Vue` не увидит данных изменений. Больше про то, как работает "реактивность" вы можете прочитать здесь: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

`computed` свойства же нужны для того, чтобы вернуть результат некой операции над свойством, например размер массива

```
computed: {
    arrModelLength() { return this.arrModel.length; }
}
```

В данном случае, вам стоит воспользоватся хуком состояния `created` (больше об хуках жизненного цикла [https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Хуки-жизненного-цикла-экземпляра](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#%D0%A5%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B0))

```
template:'<my-select v-bind:arr="arrModel"></my-select>',
data: { arrModel: [] }, //не имеет смысла делать данное свойство `computed`
created() {
    axios.get('/api/some').then((response) => { this.arrModel = response.data.arrayOfOptions; });
}
```

**UPDATE**

В случае с `vuex` вам здесь не нужно `computed` свойство. Используйте `getters`

```
getters: {
    arrModel: state => [...new Set(state.history.map(historyEntry => historyEntry.modelID))]
}
```

Comment: Немного не так, запрос происходит не в computed, результат запроса записываю в Vuex.Store, в computed происходит обработка запроса, т.е. arrModel:function(){
    var list=[];
    var history=this.$store.state.user.history;
    for (var i = 0; i < history.length; i++) {
     if (list.indexOf(history[i].modelID)===-1) list.push(history[i].modelID);
    }
    return list;
   }, и как бы все хорошо, все считается все в консоле выводится, но обновленный селект не отображается, только при повторной загрузке всей страницы.

Comment: @Komok ну, хотя бы тег поставили бы... Обновил ответ

Comment: не получается так, не рендерится селект, на подобии compile в AngularJs может нужно, чтоб обновить список? Вот если в шаблоне просто выводить {{arrModel}}? то все норм, подозреваю что все дело в том что нужно как то рендер запускать, пробывал через render, эффект тот же. С vue недавно знаком.

Comment: @Komok, можете скинуть полный код компонентов и state'ов нужных файлов? Еще лучше будет, если скинете это все в каком-нибудь jsbin.com jsfiddle

Comment: обновил вопрос ...

Comment: @komok у вас стоит инструмент разработчика Vue? Если нет, то поставьте (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd) и через него отследите весь процесс. `Vue` в каком-то месте не может задетектить изменения и из-за этого у вас не работает рендеринг. Возможно проблема в том, как вы устанавливаете `state.user.history`